# How to Keypress-enter on every Browser?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

How can you make the keypress action work? 
Got a chat, with which i want to send - what else - messages. In the Form-tag (its jsp based) i got this:

```
" name="chat" target="content" onkeypress="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) SendMessage();" OnSubmit='SendMessage();return false;'>
```

the function in the script is the following:

```
    function SendMessage()
       {
         if (event.keyCode===13) {
           alert('ENTER PRESSED'); // to make sure the function is called
           document.chat.submit();
           document.chat.msg.value = "";
           document.chat.reset();
           document.chat.msg.focus();
        }
     }
```

This is working fine on Chrome but not on Firefox, but it should work on every Browser. 
In addition, this script causes firefox to not clear the textfield (i think, because the function is not called properly).
Any suggestions or help on this? i'm pretty lost..

Comment: did you try [`event.charCode`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15700208/3841803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
function SendMessage(event){
var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
if (x === 13){
//your code
}
}
```

The keyCode property may not work on the onkeypress event in Firefox. However, the which property does.

if the browser supports event.which, then use event.which, otherwise use event.keyCode

Comment: how do i add the 13 (enter) here? Doesn't this code does the action if i press any key?

Answer (score 0):

keep html

```
" name="chat" target="content" onkeypress="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) SendMessage();" OnSubmit='SendMessage();return false;'>
```

and change function to this

```
function SendMessage()
{
    alert('ENTER PRESSED'); // to make sure the function is called
    document.chat.submit();
    document.chat.msg.value = "";
    document.chat.reset();
    document.chat.msg.focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. sadly, this works in Firefox but not in google chrome. :(
If I press enter, the alert will come but the document won't send the message with   'document.chat.submit();'

Comment: Both two methods are failed?

Comment: @arserenko My bad, sorry. I changed the answer

Comment: yep.. both failed. it works in FF like i said but not in Chrome, maybe because of the keypress?

Answer (score 0):

Try `onkeyup`:

```js
var chat = document.chat;// chat form
var send = function() {
  chat.msg.value = '';
  chat.msg.focus();
};

var trySend = function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (13 === k)
    send();
};
```

```html
<form name='chat' onsubmit='send();return false;'><!-- won't submit form -->
  <textarea name='msg' onkeyup='trySend(event)'></textarea>
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: holy crap this worked. i now got what you told. also this was a probelm of the "keypressed". keyup fixed it as well. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form[name="chat"]').on('keyup', function(e){
        if (e.which === 13) {
            alert('ENTER PRESSED'); // to make sure the function is called
            document.chat.submit();
            document.chat.msg.value = "";
            document.chat.reset();
            document.chat.msg.focus();
        }
});
```