# $(document).on("keypress" - Not triggered in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, keypress

Code:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".className", function (e) {
     debugger;
     if (e.which == 13) {
     debugger;
           ....
           ...
    }
}
```

Above code triggers in `IE`, `CHROME` but ***not works*** in `FIREFOX`

Note:
I had already refer the following SO links related to this, but nothing makes firefox to trigger..

[onKeyPress event not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496910/onkeypress-event-not-working-in-firefox)

[Key press event is not working in Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235689/key-press-event-is-not-working-in-mozilla-fire-fox)

[keypress is not working in Mozila Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699654/keypress-is-not-working-in-mozila-firefox)

Comment: Assuming the missing `)` at the end of your code is a typo, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zq2tefa6/ - just tested in FF39

Comment: It doesn't works for me..

Comment: clearly some code you aren't showing is the problem, works here for firefox 42 and 44

Comment: I too get `ReferenceError: event is not defined` only in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/6knunwLp/

Comment: Works Fine in `IE` / `Chrome`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `e.charCode` in Firefox.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".className", function (e) {
     var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
     if (code == 13) {
     debugger;
           ....
           ...
    }
});
```

Comment: any issue with `e.which`.

Comment: First `debugger` line of code in the question itself is not triggered.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: this function is present below the `document.ready...` function. Works fine in `IE / Chrome`